# Failed to compile latex document - Citation-style-language

Tags: bibliographies, errors, csl

I've come to a point where I really don't know where to search for a solution anymore. I'm trying to compile my thesis on a newly setup Linux-Laptop and it always gives me an error. I already switched Latex versions, the Linux distro and spent ours searching for a solution online.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec} % LuaLaTeX font management
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = my_csl}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

% Set the document language to German
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Include the fancyhdr package for custom headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{acronym}


% Define the page style with fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear default headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove the header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Centered page number in the footer

% No page numbering initially
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\include{Frontpage}
[...]
% ... include other chapters

\include{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

I can actually compile this without any problem on my desktop computer, using VSCode and the LatexWorkshop plugin. I'm pretty sure that I've setup everything in the same way. On the new OS, I get an error and I narrowed it down to the following message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/citation-style-language/citation-style-language-init.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/citation-style-language/citation-style-language-init.sty:118: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l__csl_language_code_map_prop 
                               
l.118 ...om_keyval:Nn \l__csl_language_code_map_prop
```

Am i right that this is the package causing the error? And then, how can I resolve this? tlmgr says I'm on the up2date version 0.4.5 and looking in their github I cant find any bug reports, so I guess it cant be a problem for everyone?

Thanks in advance,

Epi.

Comment: Can you modify your code so we can reproduce the error? We don't have the files you are `\include`ing so, although we'll get an error if we compile your code, it won't be the right error. I get `! Module citeproc Error: Style "my_csl.csl" not found.` for example.

Comment: If I replace your `\include`s by `Hylo \nocite{*} \printbibliography`, replace `literature` by `biblatex-examples` and comment out the call to your custom `csl`, I can compile, generate a bibliography and recompile without error. So while the error may be somewhere in the package, it may equally well lie in the code you've not shared.

Comment: That is a problem with a change in the kernel. It now errors if a prop is not correctly declared. Until the package has fixed that  as a workaround define the missing prop before loading the citation package.

Comment: Generally: do not spent hours trying to fix this on your own and do not reinstall your tex system if you don't know what is going on. This is a waste of time. Spent 15 minutes for a search and 15 minutes  for a minimal example and then ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst this is an issue in `citation-style-language` (and reported), an update to `expl3` will be out later today that will avoid the error. For the present, use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \__prop_if_flat:NTF #1
  {
    \prop_if_exist:NT #1
    \exp_after:wN \__prop_if_flat_aux:w #1
    \s_@@_mark \use_ii:nn
    \__prop_flatten:w \s__prop_mark \use_i:nn \s__prop_stop
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you very much! I actually didnt find that bug report on github? Really sorry that I missed it there. Thanks for your work!

Comment: @EnflamedSoul https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues/54